# How to download buffer data file or blob file in react native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to download file using axios in react native. I got a response as arrayBuffer that has init8Array, init16Array and unit8Array, then i convert whole response into unit8Array, but i am trying to convert that unit8Array into string file it show unexpected data that i could not understand.Help me to get rid from this problem. I also use react-native-fetch-blob.

Below are my responses :- 
[image: Axios response][image: Convert axios ArrayBuffer to Unit8Array]

[image: After convert unit8Array into string]

Here is my code :-

```
export const getDocumentDetail = (reference) => {
return async dispatch => {
    getToken().then(token =>{ 

AxiosBase.get('/document/'+reference,{
    responseType : 'arraybuffer',
    headers : {
        Authorization : 'Bearer '+token,
        Accept : 'application/pdf'
    }
})
.then(response => {
    console.log('Data',response.data)
    var bufferData = Buffer.from(response.data)
    var string = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(bufferData);
    console.log('Buffer : ',bufferData,string)
    dispatch({
        type : DOCUMENT_DETAIL,
        documentDetail : response.data
    })
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log('Documents Error : ',error)
})
    })
}
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: please check my code..

Comment: Your file is a pdf, that's binary data, converting it to a text file won't do any good. What do you want to do with the File?

Comment: i just want to show file in webview or pdf viewer...

Comment: or download file...

Comment: Then why do you try to convert it as text? All you need is a Blob: `blob = new Blob([ response.data ])`. To display or download it, create a blobURI pointing to it `URL.createObjectURL( blob )`. That is for WEB APIs at least.

Comment: but i don't know how to view that blob file in webview or pdf...

Comment: let me try this...

Comment: Now i have a blob Link:-  blob:a47b6e3e-dbb6-4b09-b722-a8d694f45d26?offset=0&size=169768, Now what i have to do next?

Comment: open the link in new tab to download. Or use any pdf viewer to view it using the url